# how to convert django-rest-framework to list of json data

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

In `AdvanceSearchViewSet`

```
class AdvanceSearchViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    queryset =  SeekerRegister.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MainSeekerSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = SeekerRegister.objects.all()
        return queryset
```

In the browser I am getting actual API.

but in console when I am printing the queryset

```
 <QuerySet [<SeekerRegister: soubhagya>]>
```

it is coming like this.

How can I get it in json format when i print in console.

Because I have to edit the data before send it to the browser.

Comment: do `serializer=MainSeekerSerializer(queryset,many=True)`

Comment: where i need to add this

Comment: do i need to return this??

Comment: posted as answer

Comment: You can also use simple APIView

Comment: @soubhagya Where you are trying to print the `queryset` currently?

Comment: @soubhagya Why do you need a `print()` ? The response you've got will be the same if you convert the queryset to a JSON format

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the serializer of your view: `MainSeekerSerializer(queryset, many=True).data`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
from rest_framework import Response

class AdvanceSearchViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    queryset =  SeekerRegister.objects.all()

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = SeekerRegister.objects.all()
        serializer=MainSeekerSerializer(queryset,many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```